# Distribution of Distributions | percent point function

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, python, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have the following normal distribution (Primary Distribution):

Mean = 7

Sigma = 0.5

[image]

and a list of other normal distributions (Secondary Distributions):

[image]

(python list of tupels, each tupel contains the index, mean, sigma of a distribution)

```
index_mean_sigma = [

(1, 8788, 1758), 

(2, 22938, 3331),

(3, 30744, 3679),

(4, 39318, 4059), 

(5, 50463, 4631),

(6, 61408, 5122),

(7, 73205, 5639), 

(8, 85501, 6152), 

(9, 94910, 6434), 

(10, 106133, 6814)

]
```

The rounded results from the Primary distribution are directly connected to the index of the Secondary Distributions. E.g. a drawn sample of 7.8 drawn from the Primary Distribution will result in the use of the Secondary Distribution with the index 8, mean 85501, sigma 6152.

In reality I will draw a single value from the Primary Distribution and then use the Secondary Distribution to draw the final value.
My questions is now, at which value do I have a confidence boundary of 95% that other drawn samples have a lower value?

### EDIT:

To make an intuitive example:

The Primary Distribution simulates the probability of me arriving at a gas station at a specific hour of the day (e.g. value 7 == 7pm, but sometimes I arrive earlier, sometimes later).
The Secondary Distributions simulates the probabilities of the fuel Prices per hour of a day (the later it gets the more expensive the fuel gets but it also effects the Standard Deviation in this case).

Now a friend asks me, how much he probably needs to pay for the fuel at the gas Station. My answer would be with a confidence Level of 95% i am sure that you will pay less than value X.

My question therefore is, can I calculate value x analytically?

---

I know that with the following function I can calculate the value for a single distribution, but I am unsure as how to handle the above mentioned problem.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.ppf(p_value, loc=mean, scale=sigma)
```

Disclaimer:
I am a beginner in statistics.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate how exactly you are drawing samples from each distribution, how are they used sequentially?

Comment: The answer will depend on what, precisely, "other drawn samples" means and how many of them there are.  Please flesh out your question with this essential information.  Perhaps you could present a small example of the process you are going through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution requires only a univariate root finder and a function to compute the standard Normal cumulative distribution (CDF) $\Phi_{0,1}.$  Obtaining the solution requires only the most basic knowledge of the family of Normal distributions and the axioms of probability, as I will describe.

---

Your price (let's call it $X$) has a *mixture* distribution: it has 10 Normal components indexed by $i=1,2,\ldots,10$ and, letting a random variable $Z$ follow the Normal distribution with mean $7$ and standard deviation $1/2,$ the indexes $i$ are chosen randomly with probabilities $p_i$ ("mixing proportions") given by

$$\Pr(i) = \Pr(i-1/2 \lt Z \le i+1/2) = \Pr([Z]=i).\tag{1}$$

For notational convenience, I have written $[Z]$ for the rounded version of $Z.$  (These probabilities need to sum to unity.  I will presume that when $Z\le 1/2$ you choose index $i=1$ and when $Z\gt 10+1/2$ you choose index $i=10.$  Thus, for instance, $[-\pi]=1$ and $[100] = 10.$)  A plot of the $p_i$ shows that only three of the components really matter, but let's continue using them all.

[image: ![Barplot of probabilities]

The distribution of $X$ *conditional* on $i$ is Normal with the specified parameters.  **Our task, then, is to find a formula for the distribution function in terms of the given information.**

The cumulative distribution function of $X$ is the object needed to answer questions like "What is the chance the price is less than $x$?" where $x$ is any possible price, such as 80000.  This chance can be expressed by breaking up the event $X\le x$ into events of the form $X\le x\text{ and }Z=i.$ Because these events are disjoint, their probabilities add and because they cover all possibilities, they add up to the desired probability:

$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X\le x) = \sum_{i=1}^{10}\Pr(X\le x\text{ and } [Z]=i).$$

These joint probabilities may, in turn, be written in terms of *conditional* probabilities using the multiplication rule $$\Pr(X\le x\text{ and }[Z]=i) = \Pr(X\le x\mid Z=i)\Pr([Z]=i),$$ whence

$$F_X(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{10}\Pr(X\le x\mid Z=i)\Pr([Z]=i).\tag{2}$$

The left hand probabilities in the sum are given by the CDFs of the price distributions specified by the indexes $i.$

We have reduced the calculation to Normal CDFs.  As a matter of notation, let $\Phi_{\mu,\sigma}$ be the CDF of the Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$  It is a basic property of Normal distributions that these are all given by the standard Normal CDF $\Phi_{0,1}$ *via*

$$\Phi_{\mu,\sigma}(x) = \Phi_{0,1}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right).$$

In these terms $(1)$ can be computed

$$\Pr([Z]=i) = \Phi_{7,1/2}(i+1/2) - \Phi_{7,1/2}(i-1/2)$$

(with the cases $[Z]=1$ and $[Z]=10$ treated a little differently, using $+\infty$ in place of $10+1/2$ and $-\infty$ in place of $1-1/2$).

The other terms in $(2)$ are computed from the means $\mu(i)$ and standard deviations $\sigma(i)$ associated with $i$ as

$$\Pr(X\le x\mid Z=i) = \Phi_{\mu(i),\sigma(i)}(x).$$

If you like, you may assemble this into a single formula:

> $$F_X(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{10}\Phi_{\mu(i),\sigma(i)}(x)\,(\Phi_{7,1/2}(i+1/2) - \Phi_{7,1/2}(i-1/2)) \tag{3}$$

(again taking care with the cases $10+1/2$ and $i-1/2$).

Here is a plot of $F_X$ (in black) along with the CDFs of the ten components of the mixture as weighted by their probabilities:

[image: Figure showing CDFs]

Because the question uses *density* functions to display the mixture components, here is a corresponding plot of those densities (in green) showing how their weighted sum gives the density of $F_X$ (black):

[image: Figure showing density functions]

**To answer questions of the form "for what price $x$ is there a $95\%$ chance I will pay less than $x$?" you need to *invert* this formula:** that is, you need to solve the equation

$$F_X(x) = \frac{95}{100}.$$

*This cannot be done analytically.*  However, a numerical solution is easy to come by because $F_X$ is strictly increasing.  That means the function

$$x\to F_X(x) - 95/100$$

has a unique root.  It's pretty obvious from the graphs in the question that this root is positive and lies somewhere around $90000,$ but it suffices to start with a conservatively high bound for the solution.  Employ any root finder you like: bisection, secant method, etc.  Bisection is *guaranteed* to work provided you start with valid lower and upper bounds for the solution and it won't be terribly expensive.  Indeed, you could simply plot $F_X$ precisely and read solutions off the graph.

As an illustration, the horizontal gray line in the previous plot of CDFs shows the 95% level.  The value of $x$ at which the black graph of $F_X$ reaches this level is shown in both the previous plots as a vertical tan line.  This value is $x=88760.$  It should be visually evident that this value cannot be found by solving comparable equations for the components and somehow combining them: you *must* invert the formula $(3).$

---

Although the question specifies interest lies in a Python solution, a commenter requested the `R` code used to make the illustrations.  Because it may illuminate the details, here it is.

```
#
# Create a data structure to describe the information.
#
hour <- c(-Inf, 1:9, Inf)
p <- diff(pnorm(hour+1/2, 7, 0.5)) # Mixing proportions
hour <- 0:10

theta <- matrix(c(8788, 1758, 
                  22938, 3331,
                  30744, 3679,
                  39318, 4059, 
                  50463, 4631,
                  61408, 5122,
                  73205, 5639, 
                  85501, 6152, 
                  94910, 6434, 
                  106133, 6814), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, 
                dimnames=list(NULL, c("Mean", "SD")))
#
# Display the mixing proportions.
#
mai <- par("mai")
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(mai=c(1.25,0.82,0.62,0.42))
plot(hour[-1]-1/2, p, type="h", xaxt="n", lwd=2, bty="n",
     xlab="", main="Mixing proportions")
s <- paste0(hour[-length(hour)], ":30-", hour[-1], ":30 pm ")
s[1] <- paste0("Before ", hour[2], ":30 pm")
s[10] <- paste0("After ", hour[10], ":30 pm")
mtext(side=1, text=s, at=hour[-1]-1/2, las=2, adj=1, cex=0.8)
#
# Create CDF and PDF functions for Gaussian mixtures.
# `x` is the argument, `theta` the Gaussian parameters (by rows), `p` the proportions.
#
pmix <- Vectorize(function(x, theta, p) {
  sum(p * pnorm(x, theta[,1], theta[,2]))
}, "x")
dmix <- Vectorize(function(x, theta, p) {
  sum(p * dnorm(x, theta[,1], theta[,2]))
}, "x")
#
# Find the 95th percentile of the mixture.
#
alpha <- 0.95
r <- range(apply(theta, 1, function(theta) qnorm(alpha, theta[1], theta[2])))
x.0 <- uniroot(function(x) {pmix(x, theta, p) - alpha}, lower=r[1], upper=r[2])$root
#
# Illustrate the solution.
# (1) Density graphs.
#
par(mai=c(0.82,0.82,0.62,0.42))
curve(dmix(x, theta, p), r[1], r[2], lwd=2, main="Price Distribution",
      ylab="Density", xlab="Price")
for(i in 1:length(p)) {
  curve(dnorm(x, theta[i,1], theta[i,2])*p[i], add=TRUE, col=hsv(2/6,.9,i/length(p)), lwd=2)
}
curve(dmix(x, theta, p), add=TRUE)
abline(v=x.0, lwd=2, col="Tan")
#
# (2) Cumulative graphs.
#
par(mai=c(0.82,0.82,0.62,0.42))
curve(pmix(x, theta, p), r[1], r[2], lwd=2, main="Price Distribution",
      ylab="Probability", xlab="Price")

abline(v=x.0, lwd=2, col="Tan")
abline(h=95/100, lwd=2, col="Gray")
for(i in 1:length(p)) {
  curve(pnorm(x, theta[i,1], theta[i,2])*p[i], add=TRUE, col=hsv(2/6,.9,i/length(p)), lwd=2)
}
curve(pmix(x, theta, p), add=TRUE)
par(mai=mai, mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much! I have two questions regarding your solution. 1. "because FX is strictly increasingI" What would happen if that weren't the case? 2. I also tried to find a solution on my own in the meantime and stumpled upon the "Dirichlet process" or more specific the "Dirichlet process mixtures for density estimation". Just out of curiosity, do you think one could approach the mentioned problem also from this perspective?

Comment: (1) $F_X$ increases no matter what, guaranteeing a zero.  However, when it's not strictly increasing there may an interval of zeros.  Any one of these solves your problem, but you might want to choose the smallest of them.  It's a little harder for a root finder to obtain that solution. (2) I don't know, because it depends on where you obtained your information in the first place and what the nature of your data and assumptions is.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Would be there supporting script (R) for this? Many thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian I have now included the code at the end.