# Interpretation of $\sigma$ in Gaussian mixture

Tags: confidence-interval, conditional-expectation, gaussian-mixture-distribution, latent-variable, conditional-variance

I have a distribution of a variable that was normalized with `plt.hist` and then fitted with a sum of gaussian curves $g_M = \displaystyle\sum_i\frac{w_i}{\sigma_i \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x - \mu_i}{2\sigma_i^2}\right)^2$, where the fitted parameters were $w, \sigma, \mu$.
I have computed the mean of the whole distribution as $u_M = \displaystyle\sum_i w_i\mu_i$ and the variance of the distribution as $\sigma_M^2 = {\displaystyle\sum_i w_i(\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2) - \mu_M^2}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)

My question is, how can I interpret the $\sigma$ ? Is it true that 68% of the values are within the interval $(\mu_M - \sigma_m; \mu_M+\sigma_M)$ like it is for a single Gaussian curve, or does it have different interpretation, since it is mixture. If so, what it would be ? The distribution looks like this [image]

Comment: If you would like to find percentiles of the mixture, you need numerical techniques such as given in the `R` code at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/424378/919.

Comment: The mixing probabilities (i.e. the mixture weights in the [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of distributions) will not be exactly knowable from your sample. I recommend a simulation approach (e.g. [NUTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246)) using a [Dirichlet random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) to model those mixing probabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not generally the case that 68% of a distribution is contained in the interval $(\mu-\sigma,\mu+\sigma)$, and restricting consideration to Gaussian mixtures doesn't really change that.

You could potentially have anything from a vanishingly small fraction (as close to zero as you care to specify) up to 100% (or rather, as close to it as you like).

The population standard deviation of the mixture ($\sigma_M$ in your notation) retains the same interpretations as it does for any distribution (albeit that it might not always be particularly enlightening or useful); it's the root-mean-square deviation from the mean; it's the square root of the variance, it's larger than the mean deviation, and so on.